# How to serialize parsed protobuf back to byte in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto, google-cloud-spanner

I have a array of proto as a db column, and I need to modify it and write it back

```
updated_proto_array = []
for proto_byte in proto_array
  parsedProto.ParseFromString(proto_byte)
  # do some modif on parsedProto here
  updated_proto_array.append(parsedProto) #original list not mutable, creating copy

# here I need to write the updated_proto_array back to db
# but I have type mismatch like "updated_proto_array is list of type 'proto', but expecting 'byte'"
```

is there an operation that reverse the .ParseFromString() and transform the parsedProto back to byte?

Answer (score 1):

`SerializeToString` confusingly creates a binary (!) string from a message.

See [Writing a Message](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#writing-a-message) and [SerializeToString](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/message.html#google.protobuf.message.Message.SerializeToString)